# PDF Rendering in Android VuDroid

Tags: android, pdf

I am using https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview to render PDFs in android. For some PDFs the rendering is very fast and clear but for some the rendering is very blurry. I tried toying with 'GRID_SIZE' field as suggested by the 'Issues' forum but that did not seem to help. Can someone offer any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using MuPDF reader(https://github.com/deepankar1994/MuPDF_For_Android).

Answer (score 0):

This lib can easily load and display PDF files:

[PdfViewPager](https://github.com/voghDev/PdfViewPager)

Hope it helps to you

Comment: I have not tested this personally but from the description on GitHub this should also be a good choice.